# What does "jaded person had to blink" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

What is the meaning of the expression in bold?

> "**Even the most jaded observer of American corporate culture had to blink** when, earlier this month, Home Depot’s board of directors handed the company’s C.E.O., Bob Nardelli, more than two hundred million dollars after pushing him out of his job."
>
> [The Sky-High Club](https://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2007/01/22/the-sky-high-club) *The New Yorker* (2007)

Comment: Have you looked for 'jaded' in a dictionary?

Comment: 1. Source and title of book/report/article, please.

Comment: 2. What is the context?

Comment: 3. Which word(s) do you not understand?

Comment: yeah it means exhausted but I can't understand the meaning

Comment: https://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2007/01/22/the-sky-high-club

Comment: @yusef799 *Jaded* does not just mean exhausted.  Did you find any other definitions that might work?

Comment: @stangdon it means also made dull, apathetic, or cynical by experience or by having or seeing too much of something. but the issue here is not about jaded it is about blinking what it means in the context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The meaning of "blink" in this context is to be slightly shocked in reaction to something unexpected and disturbing. You may move your head back a bit and close your eyes slightly longer than a normal blink while you understand what you've just learned.

In image form:
https://giphy.com/gifs/what-guy-white-blinking-RILsqUte1MME7TzQJ9

Answer (score 4):

Even people who have watched the world of business for a long time, and seen enough strange things to lose interest, would have been surprised when they heard that Home Depot's board of directors handed Bob Nardelli two hundred million dollars.

The meaning of 'jaded' that you need is

> not having interest or losing interest because you have experienced
> something too many times

[Jaded (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/jaded)

We can use 'blink' as a short way of saying 'be surprised' (people often blink when they are surprised).

> 5. to be surprised or amazed

[Blink (Collins Dictionary)](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/blink)